# How can I create a separate page according to a specific id in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am attempting to create a website using django in which people can fill out a form, which will create an instance of the "Person" model. I want to create a separate page for each "Person".

I was wondering if it would be possible to assign a specific id to each person, for example 123456, and access that person's page by going to mysite.com/123456.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is a "how to code something" question, which in general is broad and vague and not suitable for this forum. Please read [ask] to learn what is a good question. Also I'd advise you to do the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/) which will teach you exactly what you need: How to define a model, how to create forms and how to create url patterns to display objects from your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can absolutely be done and is reasonably simple.**

I shall assume that you already have the Person created from the form and such. The `Person` object is ready, it just needs to be displayed.

In your `urls.py`:

```
    path('<int:user_id>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

In your `views.py`:

```
def profile(request, user_id):
    the_user = get_object_or_404(Person, user_id=user_id)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'the_user': the_user,})
```

Then anytime you enter `mysite.com/12432` it will take the 12432, assign it to the argument `user_id` and send that argument to your view function, as you can see. The `user_id` would be used to figure out which person was wanted and would return that person and its data to the template.

[Mad Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302268/mad-wombat) has some good additional information. See his comment below. I have incorporated some of this feedback into the updated answer.

If `user_id` is the same as the default id in your database, you can use `pk=user_id` in your `get_object_or_404()`.

Comment: Maybe even replace user_id with the default model PK field, `Person.objects.get(pk=user_id)`. Also might want to use get_object_or_404() function to return a 404 on non-existent records.

Comment: Improvements added.

Comment: get_object_or_404() is a stand-alone shortcut function, `person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=user_id)`

Comment: It has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I tried your solution, I got this error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route '<id:user_id>/' uses invalid converter 'id'.
How can I fix this?

Comment: `id` should be `int`, sorry. Was adapting this from other code I had.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for! I decided to go with uuid and changed `int` to `str`.

Comment: Excellent. Glad it worked for you. If this answer completely solves your problem, click the green check mark to the left of my answer to the community knows this issue is resolved.